# Anyway to use audio over dvi

Tags: sound, hdmi, dvi

Hi I've only just installed ubuntu for XMBC works ok using speakers. But I've had a play and can't get audio to my TV. DVI to HDMI. Not sure if there is anything I can do.

Comment: Could you please add more information, like your video and audio card model (`lspci`)?

Answer (score 0):

When I had my issues getting sound out through my HDMI, it was related to not having the up to date driver for my AMD Graphics card. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems may help, I've also heard that installing Pulse Audio from the Software Manager can assist as well